# Django Filter Objects with Euclidean distance

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, euclidean-distance

Is there a way to convert the following Postgres query:

```
SELECT a FROM test ORDER BY a <-> cube(array[0.5,0.5,0.5]) LIMIT 50;
```

To a working Django Model query using the ORM? Perhaps using annotate() with that expression, then order_by()?

Comment: Have you had a look at PostGIS? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/

Comment: I haven't, but feel free to show an implementation using it.